# Field Extensions of degree $2$

Tags: field-theory

I know that if $K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $2$, then $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for some squarefree integer $d$. I understand that this is not the case for degree $2$ extensions of $\mathbb{R}$.

What can we say for degree $2$ extensions of fields of characteristic $p\in$ prime?

Comment: It is the case for degree $2$ extensions of $\mathbb{R}$, those are $\mathbb{R}[\sqrt{-1}]$, and $-1$ is a squarefree integer.

Comment: If $p\ne 2$, then the result is the same. The case $p=2$ is always odd :-)

Comment: @lhf: +1. All prime numbers are odd, and 2 is the oddest of them all :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given a field $k$ not of characteristic $2$, and given $[K:k]=2$, let $K=k(\beta)$ with $\beta$ a zero of $x^2+ax+b$. Replacing $x$ by $x-{a\over 2}$ converts this to the form $x^2-b'$. Thus, the extension is obtained by adjoining $\sqrt{b'}$.

In characteristic $2$, extensions obtained by adjoining square roots are *inseparable*, but they are still there.

In characteristic $2$, the *separable* quadratic extensions are obtained by adjoining zeros of Artin-Schreier polynomials $x^2-x+a$.

Similarly, in characteristic $p$, *separable* degree-$p$ extensions are obtained by adjoining zeros of Artin-Schreier $x^p-x+a$.